# spacing between buttons in scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

in my application i am adding image buttons dynamically in linear-layout in scroll-view.but there is no spacing in between the image buttons.can any one help me in giving space between image buttons.
here is my code.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

scrollview=(ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
LinearLayout ll =( LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollinear);

ImageButton img_travel = new ImageButton(this);


img_travel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.travel);

ImageButton img_work=new ImageButton(this);
img_work.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.work);

ll.addView(img_work);
ll.addView(img_travel);

setContentView(v);
```

Comment: you can add padding to your buttons

Comment: addMarginTop before adding img_travel button

Answer (score -2, accepted):

TRy this...

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

scrollview=(ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
LinearLayout ll =( LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollinear);

ImageButton img_travel = new ImageButton(this);


img_travel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.travel);

ImageButton img_work=new ImageButton(this);
img_work.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.work);

View dummyView= new View(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(your width in dp, your height in dp);

dummyView.setLayoutParams(viewParams )

ll.addView(img_work);
ll.addView(dummyView);
ll.addView(img_travel);

setContentView(v);
```

Comment: Why are you using an extra view, and keeping a dummy object in your layout, for doing what you can do with a basic attribute? This solution is not good for this, and will be terrible if you have a lot of views and want to have margins brtween them.

Comment: @CarlosRobles: Of course that, was very bad practice. Just i want to give a simple, straight solution. I think he is beginner, Once he got the grip on UI design, he will come to know best practice...

Comment: When you are a beginner is ehen you havr to get used to good habits.  Probably not to complex design patterns, but the good way here is just a function call.  Easy to understand.  You cannot recommend something that inappropriate to a beginner since you confuse him. As you can se in a -2 score acepted answer

Comment: Ok.. sorry. I will not repeat this again. Thanks for correcting me... :)

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 layoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);


  ll.addView(img_work, layoutParams);
```

Comment: excuse my brevity, I wrote it from my mobile